# Laplace Transform of integrals

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

How do I prove that the Bessel function $J_0 = {1\over \pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(x\cos(t))dt $ using Laplace transforms? I was able to solve a similar problem by finding the transform of the integrand by regarding the $t$ terms as constants and then finding the inverse, but I just don't seem to understand the logic. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $J_0$? Do you have any other representation? The formula you give is sometimes used as a definition...

Comment: @mickep -  for this question, $J_0$ is the function whose Laplace transform is ${1\over \sqrt(1+p^2)}$.

Comment: use definition.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
{\cal L}(J_0)
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}{1\over \pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(x\cos(t))dt \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}{1\over \pi}\int_0^\pi \dfrac12\left(e^{ix\cos t}+e^{-ix\cos t}\right)dt \, dx \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi \left(e^{ix\cos t-sx}+e^{-ix\cos t-sx}\right)dt \, dx \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty \left(e^{ix\cos t-sx}+e^{-ix\cos t-sx}\right)dx \, dt \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \dfrac{e^{ix\cos t-sx}}{i\cos t-s}+\dfrac{e^{-ix\cos t-sx}}{-i\cos t-s}\Big|_0^\infty \, dt \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \dfrac{1}{s-i\cos t}+\dfrac{1}{-s-i\cos t} \, dt \\
&= \dfrac{s}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \dfrac{1}{s^2+\cos^2t} \, dt \\
&= \dfrac{s}{\pi} \dfrac{\pi}{s\sqrt{s^2+1}}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

> In general:
>
> For the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition):
>
> - $$\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right):=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{f}\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(x\right)\cdot
>      e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$
>
> For the [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Definitions):
>
> - $$\mathcal{J}_\alpha\left(x\right):=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\alpha+2\text{n}}\tag2$$

---

So, we get:

$$\text{F}_\alpha\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\mathcal{J}_\alpha\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{J}_\alpha\left(x\right)\cdot
   e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_0^\infty\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\alpha+2\text{n}}\cdot
   e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\alpha+2\text{n}}\cdot
   e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}{2^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}\cdot
   e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}\cdot\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha+2\text{n}}\cdot
   e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

Now, using [the qth power (for complex q) Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms):

$$\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha+2\text{n}}\cdot
   e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+2\text{n}\right)}{\text{s}^{1+\alpha+2\text{n}}}\tag4$$

When $\Re\left(\text{s}\right)>0\space\wedge\space\Re\left(\alpha+2\text{n}\right)>-1$

So, we end up with:

$$\text{F}_\alpha\left(\text{s}\right)=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+2\text{n}\right)}{\text{s}^{1+\alpha+2\text{n}}}\tag5$$

> Now, when $\alpha=0$:
>
> $$\text{F}_0\left(\text{s}\right)=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+2\text{n}\right)}{\text{s}^{1+2\text{n}}}=\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\text{s}^2}}}\tag6$$
>
> When $\frac{1}{\left|\text{s}\right|}<1\space\wedge\space\Re\left(\text{s}\right)>0$